# Is it possible for me to play the game Hearthstone on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian

I'm planning to sell off my $800.00 laptop and was wondering if the title is at all possible? I'm extremely new to linux and have only memorized the cmd to shutdown so far. I'm aware that there s a program called wine but hated it when it didn't work to my liking when I had an ubuntu desktop for a short period of time last year.

So I guess the real question is: is there a stable way to play the game "Hearthstone" on my raspberry pi that is preferably easy to setup or if not, could somewhat be kind enough to write or link me to a set-by-step noob friendly detailed guide.

Cheers!

Zach

Comment: No, it is just too heavy run on raspi.

Comment: If it did not run satisfactorily on your laptop it is unlikely that it will do so on the Raspberry Pi. Remember the pi is roughly equivalent to a 300MHZ Pentium.